# Spring Security OAuth2 PrincipalExtractor doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I just tried to save OAuth2 user login data to db (h2) using PrincipalExtractor, but it doesn't seem to work for me. After login there is no reaction from PrincipalExtractor, even though I registered the bean.
Database and authentication works fine.

application.yml (security part)

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          discord:
            client-id: "secret"
            client-secret: "secret"
            clientAuthenticationMethod: post
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            scope:
              - identify
            redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/discord"
            clientName: discordms
        provider:
          discord:
            authorizationUri: https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize
            tokenUri: https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token
            userInfoUri: https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me
            usernameAttribute: username
```

PrincipalExtractor class

```
public class DiscordPrincipalExtractor implements PrincipalExtractor {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  public DiscordPrincipalExtractor(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public Object extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Optional<UserEntityImpl> user = this.userRepository.findById((long) map.get("id"));

    if (!user.isPresent()) {
      user = Optional.of(new UserBuilder()
          .withIdentifier((long) map.get("id"))
          .withUsername((String) map.get("username"))
          .withDiscriminator((int) map.get("discriminator"))
          .withAvatarHash((String) map.get("avatar"))
          .withLocale((String) map.get("locale"))
          .withAvatarUrl("https://cdn.discordapp.com/" + map.get("id") + "/" + map.get("avatar"))
          .withCreated(LocalDateTime.now())
          .withLastLogin(LocalDateTime.now())
          .build());
    } else {
      user.get().setLastLogin(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    this.userRepository.save(user.get());

    return user.get();
  }

}
```

and the security config class

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .tokenEndpoint()
        .accessTokenResponseClient(new RestOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient(this.restOperations()))
        .and()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
        .userService(new CustomOAuth2UserServiceImpl(this.restOperations()));
  }

  @Bean
  public PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor(UserRepository userRepository) {
    return new DiscordPrincipalExtractor(userRepository);
  }

  @Bean
  public RestOperations restOperations() {
    return new RestTemplate();
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I am facing with the same problem.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @Hinotori - I'm experiencing the same issue.  That is, Spring is not picking up the custom `PrincipalExtractor`.   I'd like to convert the oauth2 principal to a local user,  persist it to my user repository, and use it as my `Principal` in various methods.   --edit: looks like this is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894402/principalextractor-and-authoritiesextractor-are-not-getting-called